# Botón redondo no da el color que se pide | Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, xml

Quiero que un botón redondo del Android Studio tenga un color específico, el problema es que no cambia y solo tiene el color de default (azul). Con la finalidad de tener el color #343a40 el botón.

> Tengo esto:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="7"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_redondo"
            android:backgroundTint="#343a40"
            />
</LinearLayout>
```

> Y esto en btn_redondo.xml

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#343a40"/>
    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="30px"/>
</shape>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que se aplique el color debes usar: `AppCompatButton` en lugar de `Button`, tampoco es necesario definir un tinte en el botón:

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSeven"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="7"
            android:background="@drawable/btn_redondo"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

el color definelo en `btn_redondo.xml` :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#343a40"/>
    <padding android:left="1dp"
        android:top="1dp"
        android:right="1dp"
        android:bottom="1dp"/>

    <corners android:radius="30px"/>
</shape>
```

de esta forma se aplicaría correctamente el color `#343a40` que deseas:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Funcionó a la perfección, gracias!

Answer (score -1):

Puedes probar asi:

```
<Button
android:background="@android:color/white"
android:textColor="@android:color/black"
```

En tu caso sería:

```
android:background="#FFFFFF"
```

Comment: De esta forma no funcionaría el Shape, donde se definiría el color #343a40 ? Si esta respuesta se generó con ChatGPT hay que recordar que su uso esta prohibido en el sitio.